# Les vignobles « menés en bio » : menés comment etc. ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, prépositions, locutions, origine-ou-raison

> [...] une bonne partie des vignobles champenois sont *menés en bio*
>   [...] (ds. [*Lapresse.ca*](https://www.lapresse.ca/gourmand/alcools/202002/12/01-5260643-champagne-moet-hennessy-arretera-lutilisation-des-herbicides-fin-2020.php))

De quel sens de [*mener*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mener) s'agit-il ici ; est-ce l'équivalent du verbe *faire* avec un adverbe ? Est-ce un emploi ancien ou moderne du verbe avec la préposition [*en*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/0), est-il davantage associé à la viticulture, à l'agriculture ou à un autre domaine/abstraction ?

Answer (score 1):

Ce n'est pas spécifique à la viticulture ou à l'agriculture.

Le sens est le suivant:

> **B. −**
>   **2.**
>   **b)** [Le compl. d'obj. désigne un procès] Être à l'initiative de quelque chose et/ou en diriger le déroulement, l'exécution; avoir une place déterminante dans le déroulement, l'exécution de quelque chose.

L'expression « mener en bio » signifie donc ici conduire une exploitation agricole en respectant les principes de l'agriculture biologique.

On la retrouve par exemple dans le *Guide Hachette des vins bio 2020* :

[image]